# Plot of gauge coupling unification

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, supersymmetry, mssm, grand-unification

[image]

(Zoom in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PF3Z7.jpg) to see the scales.)
About the result of plotting running of 3 coupling constant, we think that we should get the correct one(MSSM).

But we get discontinuity at $ M_{susy}$.

If there something wrong in our formulae?
If you have the correct formulae of $1/\alpha$, please provide them for me.

Comment: Hi, you can find the full 2-loop beta functions in Martin and Vaughn here: http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9311340

Comment: I can't read the scales on your plot well enough to see whether they are different.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the particle content of your theory, you need to take into account threshold corrections. In order to be consistent with two-loop running you should also calculate the one-loop threshold coefficients. I guess these will make up for your dicontinuity.

Comment: What is meant by "consistent" here? Is it "making up for discontinuity"?

Comment: No. "Consistent" here means that if you take into account corrections of order $\hbar^2$, you should take into account *all* corrections to $\hbar^2$, which includes the threshold corrections.

Comment: Ah I see they are of the same order. Thanks for clarifying.